# Is there something similar to the Greasemonkey script system for a browser in iOS?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, javascript

[Greasemonkey is explained in this Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey).

I would like to add my own stylesheet to a particularly non-mobile-friendly website. Is there any way to accomplish this? Are there any browser apps that can do it?

Comment: I haven't found any at first glance. Try to check browser with ADBlocking features.

Comment: Also you can try Opera Mobile for iPhone.

Comment: Have a look at the iCab Mobile app. I'm not sure if it supports this now, but it's worth emailing the developer and asking. If any good iOS browser has it, I'd expect it to be iCab.

Answer (score 4):

You can use userscripts on iOS Safari using the new Shortcuts utility (though it seems to be complicated) and a lot easier using the free [Safari Snippets](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/safari-snippets/id1126048257) app. However, this approach does not load userscripts automatically, they have to be manually loaded on each page load.

There seem to be at least two third-party browsers which support userscripts, the [Gear Browser](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/gear-browser/id1458962238) and the [Alook Browser](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/alook-browser-2x-speed/id1261944766). I don't have experience with Gear, but in Alook you can create userscripts which are loaded automatically based on custom URL regexes (similar to Tampermonkey). While Alook has a one-time fee, note that Gear requires you to subscribe before you can use their userscript functionality (the monthly cost is currently higher than the one-time fee of Alook).

Finally, there is an external way of injecting userscripts into sites via a MITM-proxy approach. I found at least two repos, however haven't tried them out yet:

- https://github.com/SimonAlling/userscript-proxy
- https://github.com/eBay/userscript-proxy

Note that encrypted websites complicate the proxy approach as you need to decrypt your HTTPS traffic using a certificate.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment there is the [GreasePocket](http://greasepocket.wordpress.com/) project in the works.

Have a look at their website, but it's far from a finished product, it will also probably need to be run on a JailBroken device.

Comment: Yeah I saw that, but it hasn't been updated in over three years, so think it's a no-go.

Comment: Make that 7 years.

Comment: Make that 11 years

Comment: Let's assume it is a no-go no-show ; )

Answer (score 2):

[Userscripts](https://github.com/quoid/userscripts) for Safari is [currently in the process of being ported to iOS 15](https://github.com/quoid/userscripts/issues/135), as a Safari Web Extension.

It's a big task though, they'll appreciate help.